# Python cannot convert float object to str implicitly

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that converts miles to yards feet and inches for school and I'm running into problems. I used Flogorithm to put the code together and I'm getting the error "variable feet was not initialized". I then put it into cloud9 to test the code and I was getting the error:

```
line 22, in <module>
    calculateyards (miles)
line 15, in calculateyards
    print("The result is" + yards)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

The code is:

```
def calculatefeet(miles, feet):
    feet = miles * 1760
    print("The result is" + feet)

    return feet

def calculateinches(miles, inches):
    inches = miles * 63360

    return inches

def calculateyards(yards):
    miles = float(input())
    yards = miles * 1760
    print("The result is" + yards)

    return yards

# Main
print("enter a distance in miles")
miles = float(input())
calculateyards (miles)
calculatefeet (miles, feet)
calculateinches (miles)
```

I'm really bad at function calls which is why I'm having so many issues and I need help.

Comment: I don't know if this was intentional, but a mile is 5280 feet.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a strongly-typed language, so there's no implicit conversion from float to str when the concatenation operator `+` expects both operands to be a string.

You should convert the float variable to a string with the `str()` constructor instead:

```
print("The result is " + str(yards))
```

or use the `str.format` method:

```
print("The result is {}".format(yards))
```